# Subtracting Row Values from Entire Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2177 observations and 44 values.  One of the rows is of particular interest because I want to subtract the values of those rows by themselves, so that row will be zero.  At the same time, the values of those rows I used for the operation need to be subtracted from all the other rows as well and a new data frame to be created.  I'm unsure of how to do this.  Here is what I have so far, but it does not work:

```
NewDataFrame <- OldData[2:44] - OldData[519,]
```

Comment: @BenBolker `sweep` needs a matrix, which complicates this a little...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is via `sweep()`, but that will need coercing to a matrix. Some example data first:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 10:1, C = 21:30)
```

Here is the `sweep()` version

```
m <- data.matrix(df)
sweep(m, 2, m[5, ])

R> sweep(m, 2, m[5, ])
       A  B  C
 [1,] -4  4 -4
 [2,] -3  3 -3
 [3,] -2  2 -2
 [4,] -1  1 -1
 [5,]  0  0  0
 [6,]  1 -1  1
 [7,]  2 -2  2
 [8,]  3 -3  3
 [9,]  4 -4  4
[10,]  5 -5  5
```

You can also do this using `-`, but because of the way R treats a matrix (as a vector with dimensions, and filling by columns) you need to do some transposing of `m`:

```
t(t(m) - m[5, ])

R> t(t(m) - m[5, ])
       A  B  C
 [1,] -4  4 -4
 [2,] -3  3 -3
 [3,] -2  2 -2
 [4,] -1  1 -1
 [5,]  0  0  0
 [6,]  1 -1  1
 [7,]  2 -2  2
 [8,]  3 -3  3
 [9,]  4 -4  4
[10,]  5 -5  5
```